# Writing a fibonacci function

Tags: python

Write a function fibonnaci() that takes:
    a bound as an input 
    and returns the Fibnonaci sequence that its biggest Fibonaci number is smaller than the bound

fibonnaci(12)

> 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8,

Comment: Can you show what you have tried and what you are getting stuck on.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go

```
def fib(maximum):
    if maximum<2:
        return []
    current=[1,1]
    while True:
        candidate=sum(current[-2:])
        if candidate>=maximum:
            break
        current.append(candidate)
    return current
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def fibonize(bound):
   temp = 0
   lst = [1]
   while True:
     if lst[len(lst) - 1] < bound:
        lst.append(lst[len(lst) - 1] + temp)
        temp = lst[len(lst) - 2]
     else:
        lst.pop()
        break
return lst
```